# SQL Logic to order text with number?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, split, sql-order-by

This is a follow up question to an earlier post. I have a column with stings & numbers that I would like to order in sequential order.

Say the customer_id is something like:
`cust-1-2`, `cust-10-1`, `cust-2-1`, `cust-1-1`, `cust-3-1`

I want to order it by the first number in the string, and then by the second. How can I do this?

I want my result to be ordered like:
`cust-1-1`, `cust-1-2`, `cust-2-1`, `cust-3-1`, `cust-10-1`

Comment: Do you know that they are always numbers?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes it's always that format: <text>-<number>-<number>

Answer (score 4):

If the format of the string is consistent, you can use `split_part()`:

```
order by 
    (split_part(customer_id, '-', 2))::int,
    (split_part(customer_id, '-', 3))::int
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=28e3f5418b46f8d8a8fc6b994da86443)**